# AngularJS binding base 64 encoded image slowing down page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing chat application in which conversation may have more than 1000 messages with each message i am showing user photo .

Photo is base64 encoded string.

I am binding this string to image by ng-src but since there are more than 1000 messages binding base64 encoded string to each message's photo slowing down page load

any suggestion to create directive or anything else

**code:**

```
<div data-ng-repeat="message in messages">
   <img data-ng-src="{{message.usr.photoEncodedString}}"/>
   {{message.text}}
</div>
```

Comment: have you considered using bind once?

Comment: https://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/

Comment: Denieal  i have checked with bind once by this code                                                                                              <div data-ng-repeat="message in messages">
   <img data-ng-src="{{::message.usr.photoEncodedString}}"/>
   {{message.text}}
</div>                                                                                                                                               but it is still taking too much time too load

Comment: I suppose the 1000 messages aren't visible at once. You should try to only load/bind the images when they are displayed on the screen, or ideally just before. I don't actually know to implement that though, sorry.

Comment: ok... you mean i should implement like paging on scroll load more messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use canvas to draw image cached in memory.
I have written directive that does just that.

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('cachedImage', ($timeout) => {
    const images = {};

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<canvas width="20" height="20"></canvas>',
      scope: {
        name: '=',
        imgData: '='
      },
      link: (scope, element) => {
        const canvas = element.find('canvas');
        let img;

        if (images[scope.name]) {
          img = images[scope.name];
        } else {
          img = new Image();
          img.src = scope.imgData;

          images[scope.name] = img;
        }

        $timeout(() => {
          const ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
          ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,20, 20);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/sielakos/pen/eZwKKO?editors=1010