# Convert Base64 to Url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, firebase

I am trying to convert **Base64 to Image URL Format**.

What is happening is that I am making a forum. Well when a user changes avatar, I can only store the base64 of the image they want to change to.. Well almost every page has their avatar in it and it takes long to load a base64.

So to increase performance in my app, I wanted to convert Base64 to URL Or some type of non performance thirsty um ... "item"?

I am making my forum using AngularJS and Firebase and Angular-material here:

https://github.com/amanuel2/ng-forum

I am a Firebase SDK 2.3.2 programmer although I have updated my firebase database to 3.0.0.. There is something called storage now?? Maybe that can help. I am not looking for any techniques by rendering using <kbd>`canvas`</kbd> tag..
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Well you would have to create an endpoint which delivers a user's avatar based on their ID (and with proper cache headers), and then use this URL.

Comment: @CherryDT yes .. each user does indeed have a UID . but how do i create the URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS binding base 64 encoded image slowing down page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344461/angularjs-binding-base-64-encoded-image-slowing-down-page-load)

Comment: @Aaron are you kidding me? Canvas.. that must be sarcatic. Im not gonna use canvas in this project. that is just insane.

Comment: Well the question is the exact same "base64 binding slows my pages, what should I do". If a canvas-based solution worked for the other asker, maybe you should consider at least trying it.

Comment: @Aaron my problem is that i have to always render using canvas tag. That can be kinda tedius, but i have this feeling that tells me there is a easier way.. its just this feeling inside me

Comment: Can't you do a proper file upload for the image rather than using it's base64 representation ?

Comment: @Aaron i am Johnny, im using this acc since im in math class now.. but how do i do proper file upload? I mean what i basically do is extract the upload Base64. You can see line 10-15 i am doing that from the file : https://github.com/amanuel2/ng-forum/blob/master/services/encodeImageToBase64.js .. Then you see later i just save that base64 into the database.. but as you can imagine if there are many people, the database will turn into a havoc, and also it is not performance wise

Comment: I don't know FireBase at all but from what I gather using its [storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) would be better to persist images. They describe how to upload images [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_files). Then you can refer to the uploaded file by a generated URL, which should avoid the heaviness of loading base64 in memory.

Comment: @Aaron the problem here is.. my app is based upon Firebase SDK 2.3.2 .. So, that doc wont be much help as it thinks i am using Firebase SDK 3.0. ... if this is the case, is this task impossible of a sort? can i somehow upload user images to Imgur, and then get the URL? or tinypic?

Comment: Gotta go to third period @Aaron ill come back in lunch and see if there are any anwsers

Comment: Sorry, I should have checked the version. Looks like there is no storage outside of the database in Firebase 2.X, so either you store your images in base64 in the database but face the problem of slow loads, either you upgrade to Firebase 3 and use the storage, or you can indeed upload the images to a server, be it imgur's, tinypic's or yours

Comment: @Aaron how can i upload image to server?

Comment: It depends on the server, but generally with a POST request which data contains the image

Comment: @Aaron nono, im trying to actually convert the base64 large request, into a URL...